# Perl Regular expression remove double tabs, line breaks, white spaces

Tags: regex, perl

I want to write a perl script that removes double tabs, line breaks and white spaces.

What I have so far is:

```
$txt=~s/\r//gs;
$txt=~s/ +/ /gs;
$txt=~s/\t+/\t/gs;
$txt=~s/[\t\n]*\n/\n/gs;
$txt=~s/\n+/\n/gs;
```

But,
1. It's not beautiful. Should be possible to do that with far less regexps.
2. It just doesn't work and I really do not know why. It leaves some double tabs, white spaces and empty lines (i.e. lines with only a tab or whitespace)

I could solve it with a while, but that is very slow and ugly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a bit un-clear. If you have a line like "  ab  TABcTABTAB  \n\n", what do you want as a result? I am reading the above as "ab c\n"?

Comment: In other words, is it correct that you want: 1. All the whitespace (e.g. any amount of spaces and tabs) in the middle of the lines converted to a single space? 2. All the whitespace at the beginning OR end of the line removed (except for newlines)? 3. Remove completely empty lines?

Comment: Exactly.
Maybe this helps:

$txt="\nRemove empty line at beg.".
     "\n\nRemove double empty line,      double spaces and ending space: \n".
     "\n and beginning. Same for tabs\t\n".
     "\tSame for Tab at beginning and multiple tabs \t\t\t and line break at end:\n\n\n"; Should in the end remove all mess except the 3 \n that actually divide the lines. So text with trash should become easily readable with no excess nl, tabs or spaces.

Comment: Update: I think I've got it. Let me open another question with the solution, I will post the link here.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a bit of a mish-mash of stuff in there, not all of which corresponds to what you said. Let's break down what you have and then perhaps you can work from there to what you want.

```
$txt=~s/\r//s; # removes a single \r from the line. Did you mean to use g on this one?
$txt=~s/[\t ]\n//s; # match a single \t OR space right before a \n, and remove. 
$txt=~s/ +/ /gs;# match at least 2 spaces, replace with a single space
$txt=~s/\t+/ /gs;# match at least 2 \t, replace with a single space
$txt=~s/\n /\n/s;# remove a space immediately following a \n
$txt=~s/\t /\t/s;# remove a space immediately following a \t
$txt=~s/\n+/ /gs;# match at least 2 \n, replace them all with a single space
```

I have the feeling that's not at all what you want to accomplish.

I'm honestly unclear on what you want to do. The way I read your stated intent, I would have thought you'd want to replace all double tabs with single tabs, all double line breaks with single line breaks, and all double spaces with single spaces. I'll further surmise that you want to actually do runs of those characters, not just doubles. Here's the regexes for what I've just said, hopefully that will give you something to go on:
(I've also removed all \r).

```
$txt=~s/\r//gs;# remove all \r
$txt=~s/\t+/\t/gs;# replace all runs of > 1 tab with a single tab
$txt=~s/\n+/\n/gs;# replace all runs of > 1 \n with a single \n
$txt=~s/ +/ /gs;# replace all runs of > 1 space with a single space
```

Given that your attempted regexes don't seem to match the way I read your stated desire, I suspect that there's some fuzziness about what you really want to do here. You might want to think further about what you are trying to accomplish, which should help the regexes become clearer.

Comment: Thank you! I seem to have been unclear, I'm sorry but will learn for the future :). Your answer helped me in solving the problem, so thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

As I try to work out a quick real answer for you, have you looked at the docs (and no I'm not just saying rtfm). `perldoc` is a great tool and has some useful info, may I suggest `perldoc perlrequick` and `perldoc perlreref` to get you going.

First of all, you might find it easier to split the long text into lines and operate on the lines separately and then join them again. Also if we make a new array to store the results to be joined we can easily exclude empty lines.

Finally, it strikes me that in operating on a long block of text, that text is likely to be external to your script. If you are really opening a file and globbing it into a variable, you could more easily do what I am leaving in as a comment block. To use this method comment the first block and remove the comment on the second block, the third block remains for either method. I include this because if you really are reading in a file then splitting it, it saves a lot of work to just read it in line by line. You could then write it out to another file if desired.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @return_lines;

### Begin "text in script" Method ###
my $txt = <<END;
hello  world  

 hello world  
hello    world
hello   world
END
#note last two are to test removing spaces after tabs

my @lines = split(/\n/, $txt);
foreach my $line (@lines) {

### Begin "text in external file" Method (commented) ###
#my $filename = 'file.txt';
#open( my $filehandle, '<', $filename); 
#while (<$filehandle>) {
#  my $line = $_; 

### Script continues for either input method ###
  $line =~ s/^\s*//; #remove leading whitespace
  $line =~ s/\s*$//; #remove trailing whitespace
  $line =~ s/\ {2,}/ /g; #remove multiple literal spaces
  $line =~ s/\t{2,}/\t/g; #remove excess tabs (is this what you meant?)
  $line =~ s/(?<=\t)\ *//g; #remove any spaces after a tab 
  push @return_lines, $line unless $line=~/^\s*$/; #remove empty lines
}
my $return_txt = join("\n", @return_lines) . "\n";

print $return_txt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your good answer! Unfortunately, I am sometimes having trouble understanding some special things with perlre, but generally I read the docs before asking :). Your answer is very good, but what I do not like about it so much is that it limits me to read the file line-by-line. That is very slow from my exp. (I use sysread). But your answer helped me solving my problem, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of your exact requirements, but here are a few hint that might get you going :

To compress all white space to spaces (probably too powerful!)

```
$txt=~s/\s+/ /g ;
```

To remove any white space at start of line

```
$txt=~s/^ +//gm ;
```

To compress multiple tabs to a space

```
$txt=~s/\t+/ /g ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have been to unclear about my requirements. However, this is part of what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit un-clear.

If you have a line like `ab TABcTABTAB \n\n`, what do you want as a result? I am reading the above as `ab c\n`? – DVK 1 min ago edit

In other words, is it correct that you want:

1. All the whitespace (e.g. any amount of spaces and tabs) in the middle of the lines converted to a single space?
2. All the whitespace at the beginning OR end of the line removed (except for newlines)?
3. Remove completely empty lines?

   ```
   $s =~ s/[\t ]+$//ms; # Remove ending spaces/tabs
   $s =~ s/^[\t ]+//ms; # Remove starting spaces/tabs
   $s =~ s/[\t ]+/ /ms; # Replace duplicate whitespace mid-string with 1 space
   $s =~ s/^$//ms;      # Remove completely empty lines
   ```

Please note that I used the "/ms" modifyers (read [perdoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) for details) so that I could use start/end of line anchors within a multi-line string.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I was not clear enough :(. Thanks for your answer though, this lead me to most of the solution. What I don't get: Why do you use /ms in line 3? There is no $ or ^, so it should not have any effect, right? Unfortunately, $txt =~ s/^$//ms; does not work for \n at the very beginning and end of the whole text. Do you know why?

Comment: @Scoox is right: the `m` and `s` modifiers have no effect in the third statement.  In fact, `s` is not relevant in *any* of the statements because none of them use the dot metacharacter.  Also, the fourth statement will never have any effect, since `/^$/` (with or without the `m` modifier) doesn't consume any characters.  And finally, all four statements are missing the `g` modifier.