# Recommendations for Feedback and Hint on Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

Yesterday I posted a question:
[Perl Regular expression remove double tabs, line breaks, white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547170/perl-regular-expression-remove-double-tabs-line-breaks-white-spaces)

With all your great help I was able to solve the problem. First, the solution:

```
$txt="\nRemove empty line at beg.".
     "\n\nRemove double empty line,      double spaces and ending space: \n".
     "\n and beginning. Same for tabs\t\n".
     "\tSame for Tab at beginning and multiple tabs \t\t\t and line break at end:\n\n\n";

# Works
$txt=~s/\r//gs; # * this is needed for actual $txt which may contain \r

# Following *should* replace it not with 1 space, but with 1 space or \t depending on input
$txt =~ s/[\t ]+/ /gs; # Replace duplicate whitespace mid-string with 1 space

$txt =~ s/[\t ]*$//gms; # Remove ending spaces/tabs
$txt =~ s/^[\t ]*//gms; # Remove starting spaces/tabs

$txt=~s/\n+/\n/gs;      # replace all runs of > 1 \n with a single \n

# clearly redundant
$txt =~ s/^$//ms;       # Remove completely empty lines ** does not work **
$txt =~ s/^\n//ms;       # Remove completely empty lines (beg.)
$txt =~ s/\n$//ms;       # Remove completely empty lines (end.)
```

This *works*, but is not very beautiful.

Therefore I would like to ask for two things:
1. How could I write this as a one liner? I still want to keep the comments, but I feel its super inefficient to do it in so many lines. Maybe I'm wrong, then it's okay as-is.
2. It works, but I feel it's not close to perfect. I don't need it to be perfect, but I would like to understand regexes better. Therefore: Any recommendations on doing this better? I.e. is there sth. redundant or superflous here?
3. Is there any regex tutorial on the net that gives instroduction to all the regex possibilites, and then training tasks for these?

Comment: I don't think you want to write this as a one liner. Not sure if it is posbile, but even if it is it would be too complex to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep it as a series of regexes.  I don't think it will be any more computationally efficient as a one-liner.  The complicated regex necessary would probably involve a lot of backtracking.  Anyhow, it would be more difficult to maintain.  I would just wrap it into a `squeeze_whitespace` routine.

`$txt =~ s/^$//ms;` does not work because `$` matches either at the end of a string *just before a newline*.  So if the string contains just a newline it will not match it.

`$txt =~ s/^\n//ms;` does not remove empty lines at the beginning of the string because `/m` changes `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of any line.  You just got lucky with your test data that your string starts with a newline so it matched that and stopped.  Same with the following one.  Use `\A` and `\z` or don't spam `/ms`.

`$txt =~ s{([\t ])+}{$1}g` will replace runs of tabs or spaces with just one tab or space.  However, with something like `"this \t that"` it will pick the *last* character.

Which brings us to testing.

```
use Test::More;

note "test tab and whitespace squeezing"; {
    is squeeze_whitespace("this  that"),   "this that";
    is squeeze_whitespace("this\t\tthat"), "this\tthat";
    is squeeze_whitespace("this \t that  up  ", "this that up";
}

note "test begin/end newline stripping"; {
    is squeeze_whitespace("\nfoo\n"), "foo", "newlines removed from the start and end";
    is squeeze_whitespace("foo\nbar"), "foo\nbar", "newlines not eaten if there's no newline at the start";
}
```

and so on