# regcomp expression for c style string with white spaces

Tags: c, regex

i am trying to detect an empty string or a string with just white spaces such as "      ".
It is a c application and uses `regcomp` and `regexec`.

For empty string `"^$"` works fine.

But for string with just whitespaces i am getting a problem. So far, i have come up with

`"[\\s]*(?![A-za-z0-9])$"`

Is there a better way to express it using perl style regular expression?

UPDATE:
i actually changed it `"[\\s]*(?![\\w\\d\\t\\n\\r]*)$"`

The above gives an error when i give an input such as  "    m". The error is

`"Invalid preceding regular expression"`

Comment: Youou can just iterate over it with isspace().

Comment: How about multi-line string? Do you want to take them into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `*` or `+` quantifier..

So it should be `^\s*$` or `^ *$`

`*` matches 0 to many characters

`+` matches 1 to many characters

Answer (score 2):

To test string for only white spaces, its Reg-Ex will be...

`^\s*$`

**REF:** helpful

[How to test to see if a string is only whitespace in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105815/how-to-test-to-see-if-a-string-is-only-whitespace-in-perl)